# php combine txt files with every 10 numbers

Tags: php, file, foreach

i have many log files which named with numbers.

```
100001.txt
100002.txt
...
119998.txt
119999.txt
```

Now i want to **combine them with every 10 numbers**. for exapmle: `100000.txt - 100009.txt` -> named `10000a.txt`, 100010.txt - 100019.txt`-> named`10001a.txt`, 100020.txt - 100029.txt` -> named `10002a.txt` ... 119990.txt - 119999.txt`-> named`11999a.txt`.
**Then removed all the old files.**

```
$files = glob('/var/logs/my_log/'*');
foreach($files as $file){
    $num = str_replace(array('/var/logs/my_log/','.txt'),'',$file);//get numbers like 100000
    if($num%10==0){
        $name = substr($num, 0, -1).'a.txt';//10001a.txt
        foreach(array_chunk($num, 10) as $values) {
            echo $values.'<br>';//this will group by 1000001-1000010, but i need 1000000-1000009
            //chmod('/var/logs/my_log/'.$values.'.txt',0777);//should i set 0777 for write and remove files?
            //$txt.=file_get_contents('/var/logs/my_log/'.$values.'.txt');//get old files value
            //unlink('/var/logs/my_log/'.$values.'.txt');//remove old files
        }
        //file_fut_contents('/var/logs/my_log/'.$name.'.txt',$txt);//save into new file
        //$name=$txt=NULL;//unset var
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find out the way by myself.

```
<?php
$files = glob('/var/logs/my_log/*');
foreach($files as $file){
    $num =str_replace(array('.txt','/var/logs/my_log/'),'',$file);
    $txt.=file_get_contents($file).'/r/n';
    if(substr($num,-1)==9){
        file_put_contents('/var/logs/my_log/'.substr($num,0,-1).'a.txt',$txt);
        $txt=NULL;      
    }
    unlink($file);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this with the `fopen($filename, $mode)` function. It has an append mode that will place the file pointer at the end of a given file. From there you could use the other file functions like `fwrite()` and `fclose()`. There are some great examples on how to use fopen in the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)